# Karate : dynamically iterate through XML response and build field which need to be validated

Tags: karate

Need to take validate actual json response content from one api again expected XML response of other api which contains multiple tags.. there is no other way as per the karate need to loop through over them and and read data dynamically. Tried place javascript code inside eval..i couldn't able to read XML data and length function.. other then that out side eval i am able to read it. But need to find make it work dynamically please some one suggest me what i can do...

I tried writing for loop inside eval.. but it couldn't able to detect length method

Comment: see if these answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+xml+dynamic - otherwise I'm sorry to say your question is not clear enough for people to help, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask